# What to do with too-bitter sorbet?

Tags: flavor, ice-cream, sorbet, cherries

I made cherry sorbet according to a recipe, only to find that the cherries I'd bought have a strongly bitter taste to them (not unusual for cherries in my experience). Now the sorbet tastes strongly of cherries I'd prefer not to eat :/ what can I do to improve the flavor, either as a last-minute addition during churning (too late for this batch but useful for the future) or a topping? I'm looking to make it sweeter.

Comment: If you are looking to make it sweeter, adding more sugar or syrup would be the obvious answer. Also, on a side note, you can always let your sorbet thaw, make the necessary corrections and just churn it again.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund That is indeed useful! I was worried about adding granulated sugar while churning, as it might not dissolve well. Thawing, adding sugar, then re-freezing sounds like a good answer, if you want to make it one

Comment: Recently, I've started hand-blending the sorbet. The result is amazing. So, just add more sugar/syrup to taste and blend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're worried about the sugar not dissolving, you can add golden syrup to the thawed sorbet. It will also make your sorbet softer. I've only tried making sorbet a couple of times but when I used golden syrup, its consistency was softer than when I used sugar.

Comment: In the US, other sugar syrups (your own simple syrup, honey, corn syrup, etc) are a lot easier to come by. And yes, golden syrup doesn't really crystallize (same goes for corn syrup) so it'll be softer.

Comment: +1 Golden syrup is worth getting for this, it is a powerful sweetener and harmonious flavour to match, unlike simple syrup, corn syrup etc. Maple syrup is good too, but a little too distinctive and may hide the cherry flavours

Comment: We thought maybe some honey or a simple syrup were worth trying :)

Comment: Personally, I don't like the flavour of honey and it has a more distinct flavour than golden syrup. But, if you like that flavour, go for it. One more thing, honey does crystallize, so I don't know how it affects the sorbet consistency

Comment: Tried adding honey tonight... and it didn't freeze up. :| I'm going to let it chill overnight again, but it might be a lost cause.

Comment: Oh dear god! Now it's still nasty, and grainy, and with a chaser of sickly-sweet. I think... I think I'm going to chalk this up as a failure and stick to sweeter fruits to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Salt counters bitterness. It may seem a little odd to add salt to a sorbet, but I can assure you that it is not unusual to use salt in desserts. Adding salt will also enhance the perceived sweetness of the sorbet.

You won't need much salt. Maybe a small pinch per serving would be enough. Just be sure to note the total amount of salt you add to a batch so that you can adjust up or down in subsequent batches.